# C6001: using unititialized memory "str[i]"

Tags: c++

The program works fine, although the fist printed number is always "3452816845". I have tried initializing "str[i]" by adding curly brackets when defining the array, or by giving it NULL value, but then the first printed number is always "zero", and only then it prints what I entered. Please take a look below:

```
#include <iostream>
using namespace std;

int main() {

    unsigned* str = new unsigned[1000];

    int cnt = 0;
    char ch;
    int a;

    cout << "Please enter text: ";

    do {

        cin.get(ch);

        if (ch <=57 && ch >=48) {

            int a = ch - '0';
            cnt++;
            str[cnt] = a;
        }

    } while (ch != '\n');


    cout << "The entered numbers are: ";

    for (int i = 0; i <= cnt; i++) {

        cout << str[i] << " "; // here is where the error appears
    }

    delete[] str;

    return 0;
}
```

Comment: You do `cnt++;` before `str[cnt] = a;`, so it's already going to be at `1` the first time. Also please read [this](https://stackoverflow.com/q/1452721/10411602).

Comment: Aside from the correct answer that Blaze gave you, you should really start to use proper container classes like `std::vector`, and give your variables proper names. Writing out "count" is not that much of a hassle and improves readability a lot.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

[Do not `using namespace std;`](https://stackoverflow.com/q/1452721/). Especially not in headers, but try to not use it in plain `.cpp` files either. It's more convenient to debug code that unambiguously tells you which namespace an identifier came from right where that identifier is being used.

---

```
unsigned* str = new unsigned[1000];
```

Since the advent of C++11, "naked" memory allocation like that is frowned upon, and is definitely not necessary here.

- You *could* just use a static array (`unsigned str[1000];`).
- You *could* use [smart pointers](https://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/memory) (`auto str = std::make_unique<char[]>(1000);`).
- Best choice, use C++ containers, like [`<vector>`](https://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/container/vector), [`<string>`](https://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/string/basic_string), or (if overhead *really* bothers you) [`<array>`](https://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/container/array).

---

```
if (ch <=57 && ch >=48) {
    int a = ch - '0';
```

Do not use "magic numbers" in your code. If you want to know if the character entered is a digit, use [`isdigit`](https://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/string/byte/isdigit), which is more expressive and works even for non-ASCII encodings that might have their digits at a different location in the code table.

---

```
int a = ch - '0';
```

This isn't wrong, as the standard guarantees this to work *for digits*. Note that similar arithmetic on *characters* (the infamous `... - 'a'`) is frowned upon though, and will break as soon as you leave the realm of strict ASCII-7 encoding.

---

```
cnt++;
str[cnt] = a;
```

C/C++ start counting at zero. You just left the first item in the array uninitialized. The beauty of the post-increment is that you can do it right there where you use the index, i.e. `str[cnt++] = a;`.

---

```
for (int i = 0; i <= cnt; i++)
    cout << str[i] << " "; // here is where the error appears
}
```

Very C, and also wrong. You didn't initialize `str[0]`, so the first round through that loop accesses uninitialized memory. *If* you had initialized `str[0]` (by incrementing `cnt` only *after* using it as an index), `i <= cnt` would go one item beyond what you wrote into `str[]`, *again* accessing uninitialized memory. A loop should run from `0` to `< cnt` (not `<=`).

If you took my earlier advice to use `<vector>` or `<string>`, there's a much better way to loop through the items stored in it, the [range-for](https://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/language/range-for).

---

```
#include <iostream>
#include <vector>

int main()
{
    char ch;
    std::vector< int > digits;
    std::cout << "Please enter text: ";

    do
    {
        std::cin.get( ch );

        if ( std::isdigit( ch ) )
        {
            digits.push_back( ch - '0' );
        }

    } while (ch != '\n');


    std::cout << "The entered numbers are: ";

    for ( auto & i : digits )
    {
        std::cout << i << " ";
    }

    std::cout << std::endl;

    return 0;
}
```

Answer (score 0):

You never initialize `str[0]`, but you output it.

Comment: While correct, you really should explain to him that the `cnt++;` before the assignment is causing this.

Answer (score 0):

The problem is here:

```
...
if (ch <=57 && ch >=48) {

    int a = ch - '0';
    cnt++;
    str[cnt] = a;
}
...
```

You are incrementing `cnt` too early, leaving `str[0]` uninitialized. You should do:

```
    if (ch <=57 && ch >=48) {

        int a = ch - '0';
        str[cnt++] = a;
    }
```

Also you do have a problem in your `for` loop; You should start from 0 till the last initialized element in the string which is at index `cnt - 1`. It should be like this:

```
for (int i = 0; i < cnt; i++) {

    cout << str[i] << " ";
}
```

or

```
for (int i = 0; i <= cnt - 1; i++) {
    cout << str[i] << " ";
}
```